# GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

Spring boot application that accesses Google PubSub, Dataflow and BigQuery in java. The application is build with maven and jar file copied to Google Compute Engine virtual machine instance. when ran using `java -jar appname.jar` in virtual machine, following error is seen

```
    2018-03-04 08:11:40.469  WARN 1005 --- [           main] o.a.b.s.u.RetryHttpRequestInitializer    : Request failed with code 403, performed 0 retries due to IOExceptions, performed 0 retries due to unsuccessful status codes, HTTP framework says request can be retried, (caller responsible for retrying): https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project-name
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to construct instance from factory method DataflowRunner#fromOptions(interface org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:233)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build(InstanceBuilder.java:162)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions(PipelineRunner.java:52)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create(Pipeline.java:142)
    at com.trackers.exlon.ExlonApplication.main(ExlonApplication.java:69)
    ... 8 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:222)
    ... 12 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataflowRunner requires gcpTempLocation, but failed to retrieve a value from PipelineOptions
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions(DataflowRunner.java:225)
    ... 17 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to verify project with ID my-project-name
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.tryCreateDefaultBucket(GcpOptions.java:274)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create(GcpOptions.java:239)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create(GcpOptions.java:228)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.returnDefaultHelper(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:592)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.getDefault(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:533)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:156)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.getGcpTempLocation(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions(DataflowRunner.java:223)
    ... 17 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to get project number
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.getProjectNumber(GcpOptions.java:347)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.getProjectNumber(GcpOptions.java:320)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.tryCreateDefaultBucket(GcpOptions.java:272)
    ... 24 more
    Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
    {
    "code" : 403,
    "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
    } ],
    "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ResilientOperation$AbstractGoogleClientRequestExecutor.call(ResilientOperation.java:166)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ResilientOperation.retry(ResilientOperation.java:66)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.getProjectNumber(GcpOptions.java:339)
    ... 26 more
```

Which permission should be set? Or should I do anything else for this exception to go?

Comment: You need to authorize those services before you can use them. See the Google Cloud Console.

Comment: "Unable to verify project with ID my-project-name" Try to set the correct project id somewhere instead of "my-project-name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to verify project with ID *my-project-name*

This is probably why (unless you redacted the project name, and you didn't say that you did so).

If that's not the problem, it sounds like you might not have the correct [access scopes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts?hl=en_GB#compute_engine_default_service_account) set on the VM, especially if you're using the Compute Engine default service account.

Comment: I used service account without enough scopes